# SQL 'sa' user account not working inspite of changing password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I tried changing the password for the account 'sa' in sql server 2014. The password was changed successfully but when i try to login it keeps saying 
"login failed for user 'sa' ".

I have changed the server properties to account both Windows and SQL authentication mode(Sever Properties > Security> Server authentication) and i have also ensured that the account is enabled.

I am still unable to connect to my local server.

Please help.

Comment: Honestly you shouldn't be using the sa account for anything anyway. You should create another account and login with that.

Comment: i agree. but i need to get the sa account working.

Comment: I know this is for 2005, but I'm pretty sure the severity level still applies.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/ you need to identify the error # and severity/state to proceed here.

Comment: If you changed the server properties to enable SQL authentication , did you remember to restart the sql service afterwards?

Comment: Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536

Comment: If you read the link, you have to get the state from the error log -- not the error output on screen, that always says state 1.

Comment: Have a look: http://serverfault.com/a/36255

Comment: You [need to get state from the error log](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx). Also, to gain access and change the sa password again, you can try [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/).